# How to install USC 5.0 in 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, software-center, backport

Is there a way I can install the Ubuntu Software Center 5.0 on Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot install USC 5.0 easily on 11.04

It will cause unmet dependencies and make you hold broken packages